# Strange problem Ajax enabled MVCContrib Grid pager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

Let's explain the context: I have a person form inside a jquery dialog that has some tabs to group informations related to this person (Personal data, addresses, emails, position, etc.)

One of the tab show the Person addresses through an ajax call to this controller action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAddresses( int id, int? page ) {
    IEnumerable<AddressModel> list = _manager.GetAddressesByContact( id ).AsPagination( page ?? 1, 2 );
    ViewData["__ContactID"] = id;
    return PartialView( "AddressList", list );
}
```

then I have on the partial the following code that create the grid and the pager

```
<%= Html.Grid(Model).Columns( column => {
    column.For(addr => addr.GetAddressTypeList().First(at => at.AddressTypeID == addr.AddressTypeID).Description).Named("Tipo");
    column.For( addr => ( addr.IsPostalAddress ) ? Html.Image( "/_assets/images/PostalAddress.gif", "Indirizzo per la corrispondenza" ) : "&nbsp;" ).Encode(false).Named("Posta");
    column.For(addr => addr.StreetAddress + "<br />" + addr.ZipCode + ", " + addr.City + "<br />" + 
        addr.GetProvinceList().First( p => p.ProvinceID == addr.ProvinceID).Description + ", " +
        addr.GetCountryList().First( c => c.CountryID == addr.CountryID).Name).Named("Indirizzo").Encode(false);
    column.For( addr => 
        "<a href='/Contact/EditAddress/" + addr.AddressID + "' class='ajaxLink' title='Modifica'><img src='/_assets/images/edit.png' alt='' /></a>"
        ).Attributes( style => "width:16px").Encode(false);
    column.For( addr =>
        "<a href='/Contact/DeleteAddress/" + addr.AddressID + "' class='ajaxLink' title='Elimina'><img src='/_assets/images/delete.png' alt='' /></a>"
        ).Attributes( style => "width:16px" ).Encode( false );
    } ).Attributes( @class => "table-list" )%>

<br />
<%= Html.Pager((IPagination)Model).First("Prima").Next("Successiva").Previous("Precedente").Last("Ultima").Format("Visualizzati {0}-{1} di {2}") %>
```

To enable ajax on the pager I have used the following code:

```
$(".paginationRight > a").live("click", function(event) {
    //stop the browser from going to the relevant URL
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        url: this.href,
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {
            $("#addressListPlaceholder").html('').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Everything works very good except one thing. When I click on a paging link there are infinite request to the server as you can see from the following Fiddler screenshot. What is going to happen????
[image]

**Update:**
Following Vinzenz advice I have added the `event.stopPropagation()` and `return false` instructions after the ajax call. Then I have

- first clicked once on the Next link of the pager (request 48) and Fiddler showed 1 request.
- Clicked on the Previous link. Fiddler shows two request (49 and 50)
- Clicked again on the Next link. Fiddler reports 4 request (51, 52, 53 and 54)

Generally if I continue clicking back and forth the number of requests made to the server is always increasing.... :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would for test reasons `return false;` from this event handler, or call `event.stopPropagation();`

It could be that there's some thing going on with your code somewhere else that you have registered the same handler twice or more times and they somehow trigger each other or whatever. It's hard to tell without having more information.

However try to use my suggestions and you will see if it helps.

Comment: Hello Vinzenz, thanks for your answer. I have added the code you've suggested. Please have a look to my Question edit for details.

Comment: I think it is that you use 'live' to register the handler. Please try this with with click instead:`$(".paginationRight > a").click(function(event) {`

Comment: Before your first suggestion I have tried with both click and live to register the handler and the problem was always present. Now it seems that it is working. Thank you again for the advice, I am curious to understand more on this.... :O

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/ says: `Description: Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.` the interessting part here is the '... and in the future' it seems like that on each click either another element with the .paginationRight class is created and it gets the handler assigned which does all the requests. However I am a bit confused why they then all seem to get fired. The only thing I could imagine is that there are somehow multiple handler registered to the same element or so.

Comment: yes. I started with using live just for the "in the future" text because I am doing a complete substitution of the table markup at every paging method. The problem, as you said, is "why these requests got fired...

Comment: I have the very same problem and what finally got the calls down to 1 each was moving my javascript to the calling page and not the page with the grid on it. My guess is that everytime the ajax call was made, the jQuery reloaded as well and seem to execute more than once (and increased with subsequent calls.)

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is to live attach is to "live attach" your code:

```
$(".paginationRight > a").live("click", function(event) {
    //stop the browser from going to the relevant URL
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        url: this.href,
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {
            $("#addressListPlaceholder").html('').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

on the page where you defined the tab (the "parent page"), not on the partial view.